# Creating Event as app using Graph API results in error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Requesting the following URL as POST

```
https://graph.facebook.com/155718697782591/events?&name=Gamblers%2C+H%C3%B6gslogen%2C+H%C3%B6g%2C+Hudiksvall&start_time=2011-09-17+21%3A00&end_time=2011-09-18+01%3A00&location=H%C3%B6gslogen%2C+H%C3%B6g%2C+Hudiksvall&privacy=PUBLIC&access_token=<token>
```

creates the following error

```
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

The token I'm using is my app's access token, which is valid.

Has there been any changes recently that would've invalidated the request I'm using? I've created many events this way previously, but some time ago it has stopped working. Creating an event with my own access token using Graph API Explorer I can use the same URL to successfully create an event.

Comment: Did you  get any further with this? I am trying to create an event with the graph api explorer and getting  "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter". The string is simply of the form https://graph.facebook.com/100001877821531/events?name=hello&privacy=OPEN&location=Hamburg&access_token=<token>

Comment: I'd suggest adding the params one at a time and see when it fails. I got further with this, but I did so by switching out the access token to my page's token, which was authenticated against my app. Which was what I wanted anyway, so kind of a win-win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was some change in the API, making me not able to create events with my app's own access token.

I authenticated the page belonging to the app against the app and used that token to create all upcoming events, which was a great improvement for me anyway, having the events show up on the page instead.